# Cross build scala-reflect for 2.10 and 2.11

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to make a library cross compile for 2.10 and 2.11.  It's working great so far, but I hit a snag when I tried to address `scala-reflect`.

`"org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.11.4"`

How do I make this cross compile, since it's not a standard dependency in that it doesn't use the normal cross compiled version numbers.

Similarly, `scala-xml` has been broken out of 2.11 into a separate library.  How do I include that only for 2.11 builds when I cross compile?

The [sbt page on cross building](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Cross-Build.html) doesn't cover these cases at all.

Comment: I don't know much about cross-compiling, but on the changelog, there is a section titled "Cross-building with sbt 0.13" where `scala.xml` is explicitly mentioned: http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.11.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the `scalaVersion` setting directly:

```
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
```